# How to setup Website URLs: Help Needed

Tags: heroku, dns, keystonejs

> I have a domain 'www.abc.ind.in'  with GoDaddy
> I have created a keystone app in 'abc.herokuapp.com'
> In GoDaddy I have setup url forwarding to 'abc.herokuapp.com'
> when a user enters 'www.abc.ind.in' the user is redirected to > 'abc.herokuapp.com'
> I would like the title/url window  to show 'www.abc.ind.in' and not > 'abc.herokuapp.com
> When a user clicks on gallery, the title should show 'www.abc.ind.in/gallery' (instead of 'abc.herokuapp.com/gallery')
>
> Basically I want to hide the fact that the solution is hosted on heroku.
> What settings should I change to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a DNS issue.

You have to remove the URL forwarding and create a CNAME or some other aliasing record so that www.abc.ind.in is an alias for abc.herokuapp.com.